# How can I hide the compass icons for other player's bases?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Just started playing a new game and the world that I spawned on has dozens of compass markers for bases crafted by other players. Is there any way to hide these?

I'm up to the bit where I craft an Analysis Visor, and am expected to return to my ship by looking for its compass icon, but there's no way to find it since there's so many base icons filling my compass that I can't see it.

Comment: Not sure if this would work or not, but perhaps playing temporarily offline would remove other players bases from your view?